# FireBase Storage MetaData-Updated Time returning 0?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am attempting to use Firebase to store and sync several CSV files. Copies of these CSV files are stored in internal storage.

To update them locally, I am looping through all items within the Firebase Storage bucket, comparing the updated times between the two and then if there is a new version, downloading it.

Everything seems to be working perfectly except the metadata fetching from Firebase, the lastupdated time of the Firebase files is always returning a zero? I find this very odd, because it can download the file just fine, meaning there shouldn't be a Firebase rule blocking a metadata fetch request or anything. Is last updated time by default 0 unless is it manually added?

```
public void updateDataBase(View view){
    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FireBaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference reference = firebaseStorage.getReference().getRoot();

    final File rootpath = new File(getFilesDir(),"database");
    if(!rootpath.exists()){
        Log.i(TAG,"Folder Created: " + rootpath.mkdirs());
    }
    reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for(final StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
                final File localFile = new File(rootpath, item.getName());
                final long[] onlineFileChangeDate = new long[1];
                item.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                        onlineFileChangeDate[0] = storageMetadata.getUpdatedTimeMillis();
                    }
                });
                Log.i("Settings","LastModified: " + localFile.lastModified());
                Log.i("Settings", "LastModified:" + onlineFileChangeDate[0]);
                if (localFile.lastModified() > onlineFileChangeDate[0]) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "File deleted " + localFile.delete());
                    item.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(settings.this, "Downloaded: " + localFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });

                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(settings.this, "Update Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG,"Firebase Update Error");
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving the metadata is an asynchronous operation, which happens in the background, while your main code continues. It's easiest to see what that means by adding a few simple log statements:

```
reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
        for(final StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Before calling getMetadata()");

            item.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Got metadata");
                }
            });
            Log.i(TAG, "After calling getMetadata()");
        }
    }
})
```

When run, this code prints:

> Before calling getMetadata()
>
> After calling getMetadata()
>
> Got metadata

This is probably not what you expected, but it is working as designed, and it explains exactly why your code doesn't work: by the time your `if (localFile.lastModified() > onlineFileChangeDate[0])` runs, the `onlineFileChangeDate[0] = storageMetadata.getUpdatedTimeMillis()` hasn't set it to a value yet.

---

The solution for his (and any other problems with asynchronous method calls) is that the code that needs the metadata needs to be inside the `onSuccess`  that gets called with that metadata, or be called from there.

The simplest fix:

```
reference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
        for(final StorageReference item : listResult.getItems()) {
            final File localFile = new File(rootpath, item.getName());
            item.getMetadata().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StorageMetadata>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(StorageMetadata storageMetadata) {
                    if (localFile.lastModified() > storageMetadata.getUpdatedTimeMillis()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "File deleted " + localFile.delete());
                        item.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Toast.makeText(settings.this, "Downloaded: " + localFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });

        }
        Toast.makeText(settings.this, "Update Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Firebase Update Error");
    }
});
```

Also see:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)

Comment: Thank you! I completely spaced on it being Asynchronous that explains everything.